# Corpus analysis program

Tags: corpora, sociolinguistics

I'm looking for a program that will count information such as the most common terms in text, number of pronouns etc. I'm looking to input many song lyrics to see the most prevalent terms and the usage of pronouns and themes within each song for a sociolinguistic study. Does anyone know of any programs that can do this? I know of LIWC (Linguistic Enquiry & Word Count) but I have never used it and am hoping for a good recommendation before I purchase one.

Comment: I have never heard of LIWC, but I'm pretty sure you don't have to buy any software to do what you want to achieve. What may help you is called a concordancer. They come with different sets of features, and the one I like best is [Antconc](http://www.antlab.sci.waseda.ac.jp/software.html). It can do everything you indicated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of other programs out there as well, but a lot have flaws. Having control over what you can search and what your outputs are is really useful, so you'll need to learn some regular expressions and a wee bit of coding (not much, I promise!). The [Natural Language ToolKit](http://nltk.org/) can do this nicely if you're willing to learn a bit of python. I'd also recommend [QCLWR](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415962706) but the learning curve is a bit higher for R than for python. R and python are both free, btw.